# \clearpage after every subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, titlesec

I'd like to clear the page at the end of every `\subsubsection`. I tried

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\subsubsectionbreak}{\clearpage}
```

But this appears to force a `\clearpage` at the **start** of every `\subsubsection`. Is it possible to force a `\clearpage` at the end?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you also want page breaks between subsections that do *not* include subsubsections, and between sections that do *not* include subsections? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes I also want page breaks between subsections and sections (even if they don't include subsub or subsections).

Comment: What do your current definitions of the sectional units `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` using [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) look like?

Comment: According to @Mico's comment and your response, it seems like you just want a `\clearpage` at *every* sectional level (`\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`). Correct?

Comment: @Werner Sorry for the confusion. I don't just want page breaks everywhere. That could be accomplished by adding `\clearpage` for every `*sectionbreak` command. When I do that I have way to many almost blank pages. I really just want to force a `clearpage` at the end of every subsubsection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could include the following instructions in your document's preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand\sectionbreak{\ifnum\value{section}>1\clearpage\fi}
\newcommand\subsectionbreak{\ifnum\value{subsection}>1\clearpage\fi}
\newcommand\subsubsectionbreak{\ifnum\value{subsubsection}>1\clearpage\fi}
```

This will insert a page break every time a `\section`, `\subsection`, or `\subsubsection` command is encountered *if* the corresponding counter is greater than 1. I.e., every `\section` command after the very first such command will trigger a page break; every `\subsection` command after the very first such command *within* a given section will trigger a page break, etc.

This method assumes that your document class uses "plain" counter variables for `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection`. If that's *not* the case, please indicate how you've set up those variables.

Comment: It works if I add a \fi at the end of the macro definition, otherwise I get a bunch of warnings

Comment: @user28291 - Thanks for pointing out this omission - I've added the `\fi` instructions.

Answer (score 6):

The following doesn't require [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\makeatletter
\newif\if@subsubsectionused \@subsubsectionusedfalse
\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\let\oldsubsubsection\subsubsection
\renewcommand{\section}{\if@subsubsectionused\clearpage\@subsubsectionusedfalse\fi\oldsection}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\if@subsubsectionused\clearpage\@subsubsectionusedfalse\fi\oldsubsection}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\if@subsubsectionused\clearpage\fi\@subsubsectionusedtrue\oldsubsubsection}
\makeatother
```

It inserts a `\clearpage` before calling the traditional sectioning command based on a condition `\if@subsubsectionused`. This condition is set to true whenever a `\subsubsection` is used, and to false otherwise.

An example of code like

```
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
```

would yield a layout of

```
1 A section
1.1 A subsection
1.1.1 A subsubsection
-----------< page break >--------------------
1.1.2 A subsubsection
-----------< page break >--------------------
1.2 A subsection
1.2.1 A subsubsection
-----------< page break >--------------------
1.2.2 A subsubsection
-----------< page break >--------------------
2 A section
2.1 A subsection
2.1.1 A subsubsection
-----------< page break >--------------------
2.1.2 A subsubsection
-----------< page break >--------------------
2.2 A subsection
2.3 A subsection
2.3.1 A subsubsection
-----------< page break >--------------------
2.3.2 A subsubsection
```

Comment: This is one works best for me, the one using titlesec makes the index off by one (probably needs just some tweek, or maybe there is something in my setup)